how to color differently specific area borders in ggplot, geom_sf
I have the map of a country which has different regions on it. I would like to color the borders of some of those regions differently from the rest of the borders. Is it possible?
I know I can create a 0-1 variable that specifies which regions' borders have to be plotted differently but I have not been able to find the function in geom_sf that could do the trick.
I have seen how to plot the outside/inner borders of the whole country but not specific region borders.
Thanks in advance,

Could you provide a code example of your attempt, with available sample of data so that it can be reproduced. You can write the output of dput(yourDataFrame)
